Five numbers with median and mean
5 distinct integers between 1 and 10, inclusive are chosen. Their median is 4 and their mean is 3.6. What are the numbers?

An idea here might be to at least leave open how many numbers there are in total. This still makes for a very easy solve, but is arguably a tiny bit more compelling

That's a good idea, but it's too late to change it, because we have an accepted answer that assumes 5 numbers.

+1 An enjoyable simple puzzle.

Thank you @Will.Octagon.Gibson. Now you can try this one: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/127682/set-of-numbers-with-median-and-mean


 For a mean of 3.6 from five numbers, we need a sum of 18.
 So we need a sum of 14 from the remaining four numbers.
 To make 4 the median, we need two numbers on either side of it. So two of them must be larger and are at least 5+6 = 11.
 That leaves at most 3 for the sum of the two smaller numbers and everything is forced.

 The numbers are 1, 2, 4, 5, 6.


Yep you got it! Good explanation.
